# using of z3_update_term function for term updating

Tags: z3

The following code changes `2` to `3` in expression `e1`.

```
context z3_cont;
expr x = z3_cont.int_const("x");
expr e1 = (x==2);
expr e2 = (x==3);
Z3_ast ee[2];
ee[0]=e1.arg(0);
ee[1]=e2.arg(1);
e1 = to_expr(z3_cont,Z3_update_term(z3_cont,e1,2,ee));
```

Is it possible to do it easier? Unfortunately, the code `e1.arg(1) = e2.arg(1)` doesn't work.
The second question is how to change expressions on arbitrary depth of the Z3_AST, for example `e1.arg(1).arg(0) = e2.arg(1).arg(1)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Z3_substitute` API.
Here is an example:

```cpp
void substitute_example() {
    std::cout << "substitute example\n";
    context c;
    expr x(c);
    x = c.int_const("x");
    expr f(c);
    f = (x == 2) || (x == 1);
    std::cout << f << std::endl;

    expr two(c), three(c);
    two   = c.int_val(2);
    three = c.int_val(3);
    Z3_ast from[] = { two };
    Z3_ast to[]   = { three };
    expr new_f(c);
    // Replaces the expressions in from with to in f. 
    // The third argument is the size of the arrays from and to.
    new_f = to_expr(c, Z3_substitute(c, f, 1, from, to));

    std::cout << new_f << std::endl;
}
```

**Update** If we want to substitute `x == 2` with `x == 3` in a formula, we should write.

```cpp
void substitute_example() {
    std::cout << "substitute example\n";
    context c;
    expr x(c), y(c);
    x = c.int_const("x");
    y = c.int_const("y");
    expr f(c);
    f = (x == 2) || (y == 2);
    std::cout << f << std::endl;

    expr from(c), to(c);
    from  = x == 2;
    to    = x == 3;
    Z3_ast _from[] = { from };
    Z3_ast _to[]   = { to };
    expr new_f(c);
    // Replaces the expressions in from with to in f. 
    // The third argument is the size of the arrays from and to.
    new_f = to_expr(c, Z3_substitute(c, f, 1, _from, _to));

    std::cout << new_f << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I can use `Z3_substitute` if I want to change all `2` to `3` in formula. If we modify `f = (x == 2) && (y == 2)` and try to use `Z3_substitute` we obtain `(x == 3) && (y == 3)` when the goal was to obtain `(x == 3) && (y == 2)`. The task is to change some expression on arbitrary depth of the Z3_AST to another expression.

Comment: If the goal is to substitute `(x == 2)` with `(x == 3)`, then you provide them as parameters to substitute.